# Toggle image not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i need

- i need to toggle image onclick of event.
- like stack overflow star similar case.

html

```
 <span itemprop="location"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
            <div  style="display:block; float:right; width:auto; color:#7c7c7c;">


      <a href="javascript:void(0);" src="http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phone.png" class="favourate_dextop" id="fav'.$data[$k]['id'].'"  onClick=" favaorite(this)"></a>
                             </div>'
```

js code

```
function favorite(pointer)
        {
        $(".favourate_dextop").click(function(){
        if($(".favourate_dextop").attr("src") == "http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phone.png"){
        //$(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').attr("src", "http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phonehover.png");

        $(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
        alert("if");
        }
        else 
        {

        //$(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').attr("src", "http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phone.png");

        $(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrls + '")');

        }
        });

}
```

problem

- i need to toggle image on click of function fav().
- problem im facing  i searched google though i found toggleclass though its not working in case.
- i found helpfull  code

  ```
      // in CSS 
              .favourate_dextop{
              background: url("http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phone.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
              display: block;
              float: right;
              height: 19px;
              width: 18px;
              }

              .favourate_dextop:hover{ background: url("http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phonehover.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}

              .favourate_dextops{
              background: url("http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phone.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
              display: block;
              float: right;
              height: 19px;
              width: 18px;
              }

              .favourate_dextops:hover{ background: url("http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phonehover.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}


              // in JS
              // based on value of imageUrl, determine what class to remove and what class to add.
              $(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').removeClass('favourate_dextop').addClass('favourate_dextops');
  ```
- this code is also not working.
- only this code works onetime when click on image changes background image only once, nut i need to toggle image urls.

updated code

```
   <div class="evt_date"  style="overflow:hidden" style="overflow:hidden" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">

<a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="favourate_dextop" id="fav'.$data[$k]['id'].'"  onClick=" favaorite('.$data[$k]['id'].',\''.$name_event.'\',\''.$event_city.'\',\''.$event_country.'\',\''.$event_urls.'\',this)"></a>
```

js code

```
       var  image2='http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phonehover.png';
       var  image1='http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phone.png';

       var toggle = 1;


      $('.favourate_dextop').click(function(){

       if (toggle == 1) 
       {
        alert("toggle 1");
           $('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + image2 + '")');

       //$("#bg").attr('src',image2);
       toggle = 0;
       }
else {
     alert("toggle 0");
                           $('.favourate_dextop').find('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + image1 + '")');

       //$("#bg").attr('src',image1);
       toggle = 1;
       }
```

});

problem im facing:

- toggling from href is not working.

js fiddle: i have updted my fiddle : some changes : http://jsfiddle.net/48Lq3u60/20/

Comment: You're mixing jQuery with javascript, if you add event in html then don't do that in jQuery inside the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must improve your code....

To toggle image use:

```
$("#yourImage").attr('src', 'newlink');
```

Check a working example  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/48Lq3u60/)

Using this as example you can toggle image like this:

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/48Lq3u60/2/)

Comment: This was a guide to your needs. i've modified the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/48Lq3u60/2/

Comment: Working example with your images http://jsfiddle.net/48Lq3u60/5/ problem is the onclick  event....

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to simplify things a bit.  Try something like this:

HTML (not that your span is now a div...you shouldn't have spans wrapped around divs as that is bad syntax):

```
<div itemprop="location"  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <div class="img-wrap img1">
        <div class="img-swap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrap {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    color: #7c7c7c;
}
.img-swap {
    float: left;
    width: ENTER WIDTH OF IMAGE;
    height: ENTER HEIGHT OF IMAGE;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.img-swap.img1 {
    background-image: url('pathtoimage1');
}
.img-swap.img2 {
    background-image: url('pathtoimage2');
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.img-wrap').click(function() { 
  jQuery(this).children('.img-swap').toggleClass('img1 img2');
});
```

You'll need to swap out the image paths and enter height and width for your container, but this probably a simpler approach and a bit cleaner.

Comment: only  condition is working:    var  imageUrl='http://im.gifbt.com/images/star1_phonehover.png';
 
   $(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');

Comment: it changes background image , but i need to toggle images, your code is not working at all for my case